# Verify Domain Admins against List via AD Module for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, active-directory

I have an issue of certain administrators temporarily elevating users to Domain Admins for troubleshooting. Instead of removing said administrators from the picture, I have been asked to create a script to check the Domain Admins group nightly, and remove any users that do not belong there.

I need it to verify the Domain Admins group against a givin list in txt or csv. I could delete everone from the group nightly, then readd the desired users back, but this could create issues if someone is logging in or logging off when that happens.

Can anyone help with this? So far I have managed to export a list of users within the group by piping get-adgroup and export-csv. But I'm failing in my attempt to get the list of users and compare to an already existing list.

Comment: Please share what code you have. It will help to determine where you're having an issue.

Comment: You could make Domain Admins a Restricted Group in Group Policy, and let that remove them automatically.

Comment: mjolinor: that sounds interesting. not familiar with the workings of Restricted Group, i will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MJOLINOR had the perfect suggestion. Here are some details about Restricted Groups...

By creating a Restricted Group GPO and linking it to the Domain Controllers OU, I have been able to add my desired group to the newly created GPO, tell that GPO which users belong in the desired group, and now, every 16 hours my desired group (Domain Admins) will be verified against the new GPO. So if users are members that are not part of the new GPO, they will be removed, and if users have been removed that are part of the new GPO, they will be added.

Thank you! And I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script I just wrote for you. First you need to make a default text file with the default members. I named my file PreviousMembers.txt

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-AdGroupMember "Domain Admins" | Select Name | Out-File C:\Scripts\PreviousMembers.txt
```

Now, save the following lines in ADGroupMembersDiff.ps1 and run it any time to get a current list of members. You'll need to make sure the files are in the same location that you specify below and the file names need to be the same, too.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$pattern = ".*"
Get-AdGroupMember "Administrators" | Select Name | Out-File C:\Scripts\CurrentMembers.txt 
(Get-Content C:\Scripts\CurrentMembers.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "Name" -and $_.trim() -ne "----" -and $_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content C:\Scripts\CurrentMembers.txt
(Get-Content C:\Scripts\PreviousMembers.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "Name" -and $_.trim() -ne "----" -and $_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content C:\Scripts\PreviousMembers.txt
$comparedLines = Compare-Object (Get-Content C:\Scripts\PreviousMembers.txt) (Get-Content C:\Scripts\CurrentMembers.txt) -IncludeEqual | Sort-Object { $_.InputObject.ReadCount } 
$lineNumber = 0

$comparedLines | foreach {
    if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
    {
        $lineNumber = $_.InputObject.ReadCount
    }
    if($_.InputObject -match $pattern)
    {
        if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==")
        {
            $lineOperation = "No Change"
        }
        ElseIf($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
        {
            $lineOperation = "New User"
        }
        Elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=")
        {
            $lineOperation = "Default User"
        }
        $HashChanges = @{
        Line = $lineNumber
        Operation = $lineOperation
        Users = $_.InputObject
        }
        New-Object psobject -Property $HashChanges | select Users, Operation
    }
}
```

Here's what the output will look like.

```
Users                       Operation
_____                       ______
John Hancock                New User
Thomas Edison               Default User
George Washington           New User
Thomas Jefferson            No Change
```

Good Luck,

T|CK

Comment: Why thank you, after reading others comments I'm concerned if Restricted Groups will work for Domain Groups, although it appears so far that it is work as I have tested with my own user account, deleted me from Domain Admins, and minutes later i was readded. I will experiment with your script, thanks again!

Comment: T|CK, help me to understand what's happening here in your script.

Comment: So basically, the first bit is exporting a list of the Domain Admins 'name's. Then you are taking and comparing this list to the list generated by Get-AdGroupMember, then they are exported to the output findings. Can you explain what "No Change", "New User" and "Default User" mean?

Comment: It generates a new list of group members and compares it to the one you created with the first couple of lines. "No Change" means the user is in the previous (i.e default or baseline) list and in the new one, "Default User" means that the user was in the previous list, but not in the new one, and "New User" means that the user was not in the previous list, but is in the new one.

You can change "New User" to "Added" and "Default User" to "Deleted" if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used Restricted groups to modify the memberships of local groups on client computers. I have never used it to modify the memberships of domain groups. In fact, Microsoft states that the intention of Restricted Group is not for Domain groups.

[...Restricted Groups is a client configuration means and cannot be used with Domain Groups...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279301/en-us)

Comment: You are right. Their website definitely makes a clear statement on them not supporting the idea of Restricted Groups on a Domain Group. However, the Group Policy book I'm reading about Restricted Groups in (by Jeremy Someone) states just the opposite. It says the he recommends using Local GPP to restrict Local groups on client machines, and therefore only gives walk-throughs of this being done using domain groups such as his example of using Restricted Groups policy for Backup Operators. I'll let you know how my testing turns out.